# AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0

Tags: python, anaconda, word2vec

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/implimentaion/train.py in 
31 use_w2v = True
32
---> 33 train_df, embeddings = make_w2v_embeddings(train_df, embedding_dim=embedding_dim, empty_w2v=not use_w2v)
34
35 # Split to train validation

~/Desktop/implimentaion/util.py in make_w2v_embeddings(df, embedding_dim, empty_w2v)
90
91                 # If a word is missing from word2vec model.
---> 92                 if word not in word2vec.vocab:
93                     if word not in vocabs_not_w2v:
94                         vocabs_not_w2v_cnt += 1

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in vocab(self)
643     @property
644     def vocab(self):
--> 645         raise AttributeError(
646             "The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.\n"
647             "Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods "

AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

Comment: please refer to why this question this question should be closed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please, describe, why did you get this error?

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, "See [https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4"](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4%22).

That page explains how to adapt older code to work with `gensim-4.0.0` & higher Gensim versions.

(You will want to change your `~/Desktop/implimentaion/util.py` file to no longer use the `.vocab` property to test if a word is in a model. The fix for the particular case shown in your error message may be as simple as changing `if word not in word2vec.vocab` to `if word not in word2vec`.)